# DF.write.mode("append") at scale

Tags: apache-spark

Is the SPARK SQL family of API's for writing to a database like this:

```
 DF.write.mode("append").jdbc(url, table, prop)
```

able to work at scale?

Or is there a time that sqoop should then be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general writing over JDBC will be typically limited by the capabilities of the destination system. In general JDBC connectors are not designed for batch data migrations, and majority of vendors, have their own, platform specific bulk insert tools.

Specific writing mode like `append` has little or no impact at all.

And as always - if you have questions about performance implications of a specific choice it's best to benchmark it yourself on the platform you use, data that reflects properties of the real input and using resources comparable to the ones, you have at your disposal in production.

Comment: Sort of looking ahead so as to save time.

Comment: I have been a DBA etc. so that's fine. I am wondering what occurs under water - just inserts or bulk inserts or in the case of ORACLE are certain scripts generated - could not find this. May be I am a bad looker

Comment: Specific writing mode like append has little or no impact at all.  - Not sure I get the sentence

Comment: I take that for heavy intermediate writing - thus not batch migration - it should be OK. Appreciate the target system is the bottleneck, but it depends what happens under water so to speak - does it not?